# How to lock page/content with javascript and html

Tags: javascript, html, modal-dialog

I'm looking to securely lock content on a basic html site based on various permissions of the user.  I'm looking to have a pop-up modal appear when the user's permissions don't check out... however it seems to be that any savvy user could simply open the console and delete that element (thus revealing the page anyways).

What am I missing here? What's the best way to approach this so that no matter what the actual page can't be accessed?

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Don't load the (entire) page until creds check out.

Answer (score 0):

If content is downloaded to the client, it's always technically possible for a savvy user to access it.

You can either live with that, or alternatively do something like the following:

1. Load the basic page template without any content
2. Use an API call using cookies/other auth to get the content
3. If logged in, display the content, if not, launch the modal.

Answer (score 0):

Ok here is my answer to this one.

The answer given was agood one,  you can't hide the content truly so your options are:

1. Don't download all the stuff you want until you have auth'd the user (via cookies etc.
2. Use a simple redirect/buffer page infront of your hidden content.

In my use case (shopify)  partial downloading of store content isn't exactly configurable (or i don't have enough knowledge of their template language + theme design to pull it off!),  so I made use of javascript and cookies in order to check a user's status.  If the user didn't pass they'd get kicked back to a landing page.  Good enough!